# Powershell AWS Update-SECSecret -SecretId

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell

I am struggling to figure out how you update a secret in AWS Secrets Manager via Powershell when the secret has multiple key/values.  My code is below with the standard change, but I have two key/values that I need to update.  I tried a specific syntax with JSON, which did not take very well, and I overwrote the secure key with a simple text.  I have attached my failed code as well, but I am stumped; I can not find references to the syntax for multiple key/values.

**SINGLE SECRET(WORKS GREAT):**

```
$sm_value = "my_secret_name"
Update-SECSecret -SecretId $sm_value -SecretString $Password
```

**MULTI VALUE KEYS (FAILED):**

```
Update-SECSecret -SecretId $sm_value -SecretString '{"Current":$newpassword,"Previous":$mycurrent}'
```

**EXAMPLE AWS SECRET**
[image]

Comment: Does it fail with an error?

Comment: As I mentioned in the post, the Multi-line does change it, but it changes the whole secret into plain text secret and overrides the two values shown in the example.   It also overrides the whole value to show up {"Current":$newpassword,"Previous":$mycurrent}

Answer (score 0):

Team, after looking at the documentation in Cloudformation and AWS CLI I concluded that my JSON string was incorrect. So after playing with it for an hour or so, I came up with this format that worked.

```
$mycurrent = "abc1234"
$newpassword = "zxy1234"

$json = @"
{"Current":"$newpassword","Previous":"$mycurrent"}
"@

Update-SECSecret -SecretId $sm_value -SecretString $json
```

It seems that updating secrets for multiple key/values requires a JSON file in order to work.